# RxJS zip not called for every nested array

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the below code consisting of a nested array of arrays where each inner array contains an async function. My issue is that the inner zip does not seem to be called for each inner array chunk. This can be seen with the logs at the bottom where `chunks.length` is shown as 150 but the zip was only called 10 times. How can I call this inner zip for each chunk to process all of the async requests at once?

```
const chunks = [
    [
        {
            asyncFunc: async () => {}
        }
        ...more of the same
    ],
    [
        ...more of the same
    ]
    ...
]

const total = 0;
from(chunks)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((chunk) => {
        const asyncStuff = chunk.map((data, imageIndex) => {
          return from(data.asyncFunc());
        });

        return zip(...asyncStuff).pipe(
          map((data) => {
            return data;
          })
        );
      }),
      catchError((error) => console.log("error", error))
    )
    .subscribe((val) => {
      total++;
      console.log(val);
      console.log("------", total);
    });

console.log(chunks.length);
// 150
console.log(total);
// 10
```

Edit:

This seems to be some kind of incompatibility with https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper and the `buffer` function. If I use

```
  const wait = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  async () => {
    await wait(); // works
    await buffer(); // doesn't work
  }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem in a StackBlitz or something similar?

Comment: @AndreiGătej my asyncFunc could be the issue. I was using buffer() from https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper. If I swap in Promise.resolve('data') it seems to work more as I would have expected. Will need to see what I am missing with buffer().

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to first extract into a new array the list of calls, each wrapped into an observable:

```
const calls$ = chunks.flat(2).map(({ asyncFunc }) => from(defer(() => asyncFunc())));
```

Now that you've got an array of observables, if you want to subscribe to all of them at once and wait for all the results, the operator you need isn't `zip` but `forkJoin`:

```
forkJoin(calls$).subscribe(console.log)
```

Here's a live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yu2eti?devtoolsheight=60

EDIT based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169545/rxjs-zip-not-called-for-every-nested-array/65171739?noredirect=1#comment115218833_65171739):

If you want to received them one chunk at the time, you have to push each observable into an observable:

```
const calls$ = chunks.flat(2).map(({ asyncFunc }) => from(defer(() => asyncFunc())));

const call$ = from(calls$)
```

and then use a higher order function based on what you want:

- Do not care about the order, whenever one resolve then give it straight away: `call$.pipe(mergeAll())`
- Preserve the order: `call$.pipe(concatAll())`

Comment: BTW as you wrap a promise into an observable if you want to keep the retry behavior in case of a failure or even the fact that if you subscribe to it multiple times, the call will be made multiple times: You have to use defer for this. Otherwise all the promises would be triggered straight away

Comment: I am not trying to flatten into one result. I would like to keep the chunks and emit an event with all async responses for each.

Comment: See my ansewer edit about buffer() from node unzipper. It seems waiting on that to complete causes nothing to emit.